# MasterMind game in C

Tags: c

I have this as my homework. Have a bit of trouble coding it. I am using C as the language.

Question:

> Mastermind is a game of two players. In the beginning, first player decides a secret key, which is a sequence (s1,s2,...sk) where 0 < si <= n, Then second player makes guesses in rounds, where each guess is of form (g1,g2, ...gk), and after each guess first player calculates the score for the guess. Score for a guess is equal to number of i's for which we have gi = si.
>
> For example if the secret key is (4,2,5,3,1) and the guess is (1,2,3,7,1),then the score is 2, because g2 = s2 and g5 = s5.
>
> Given a sequence of guesses, and scores for each guess, your program must decide if there exists at least one secret key that generates those exact scores.

Input:

> First line of input contains a single integer C (1 <=C <= 100). C test-cases follow. First line of each test-case contains three integers n,k and q. (1 <=n,k <=11, 1<=q<=8). Next q lines contain the guesses.
>
> Each guess consists of k integers gi,1, gi,2,....gi,k separated by a single space, followed by the score for the guess bi (1 <= gi,j <=n for all 1 <=i <=q, 1 <=j <=k; and 0 <= bi <=k )

Output:

> For each test-case, output "Yes" (without quotes), if there exists at least a secret key which generates those exact scores, otherwise output "No".

The code I wrote is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct set_t{    
    int count;     
    void **values; 
} *SetRef;

SetRef set_create(void *values, ...); 
int  set_count(SetRef this);
bool set_contains(SetRef this, void *value);  
int rscore(SetRef set1, void *value, int score);


int main(int argc,char **argv )
{
    int t = 0, n = 0 ,k = 0,q = 0, score = 0;
    char ch;
    int arr1[n];
    int arr2[n];
    printf("Please enter the number of test cases(between 1 to 100):");
    scanf("%d",&t);
    printf("\n");
    for ( int i = 1; i<=t;i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter values of n,k, q:");
        scanf("%i %i %i",&n, &k, &q);

        printf("\n");
        printf("Enter the values of secret key");
        score = 0;
        for ( int c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
        {
            scanf("%d",&arr1[c]);
         }
        printf("\n");
        printf("Enter the values of guess");
            for ( int c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
            {
                scanf("%d",&arr2[c]);
             }

        }
       SetRef set1 = set_create(&arr1); 
       SetRef set2 = set_create(&arr2); 
       for ( int i = 0; i < set2->count; i++){
            void *val = set2->values[i]; 
            score = rscore(set1, val,score);
        }        
        if ( score == set1->count)
            printf("Yes");
        else
            printf("No");
        printf("\n");
    }
}

SetRef set_create(void *values, ...) 
{   
    SetRef set = calloc(1, sizeof(struct set_t));    
    if (values)   
    {        
        int count = 1;     
         va_list args;       
         va_start(args, values);       
        while (va_arg(args, void *)) 
        {             
            count++;    
        }          
        va_end(args);       
        set->count = count;      
        set->values = calloc(count, sizeof(void *));      
        set->values[0] = values;    
        va_start(args, values);       
        int i = 1;         
        void *val;       
        while ((val = va_arg(args, void *)))
        {            
            set->values[i++] = val;      
        }       
        va_end(args);    
    }      
    return set; 
}  
int set_count(SetRef this) 
{    
    return this->count; 
} 
bool set_contains(SetRef this, void *value) 
{    
    for (int i = 0; i < this->count; i++)
    {      
        if (value == this->values[i])   
            return true;   
    }    
    return false;
}  

int rscore(SetRef set1, void *value, int score){
    void *val = value;
    if (set_contains(set1, val))
        score ++;
    return score;
}
```

I have these errors:

> solution.cc:60:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token

Besides that, is my logic correct? Have I made any major mistakes?

Not sure how to solve this. Need some guidance.

Comment: Your source code is C++, The tag is C++, but the title is C. Which one was your goal?

Comment: The tag is now C, but the code remains C++... kinda, not valid C++ anyway...

Comment: You are probably compiling this as C++ since your extension is cc and "this" is a reserved keyword in C++.

Comment: as far as I can see the code is C, only extension is C++.

Comment: The `cstdarg` include is a C++-ism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are compiling C source code as C++.  C and C++ are different languages.

Rename your file to `solution.c` and NOT `solution.cc`, and make sure to compile with a C compiler (e.g., `gcc` and NOT `g++`)

**Edit:** Actually, it looks like the source code is neither C nor C++.  Pick one and stick with it.  It is almost C, you would need to change `#include <cstdarg>` to `#include <stdarg.h>` and you would need to add `#include <stdbool.h>` for the `bool` type.  You will also need to change `YES` and `NO` to `true` and `false`.

The `bool` type might not be available if you use Microsoft's MSC compiler, which uses an outdated version of C.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ `this` is a keyword used as a pointer to the current object inside class member functions.

You have to use some other name that is not reserved by the language.

Or, if this is actually C code, not include C++ headers like `<cstdarg>` and rename the files from `.cc` to `.c`.

Choose your language!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `this` as a variable name in C++.  It's a language keyword.  If you want to compile a C program, don't use a C++ compiler.